# Finding the joint distribution of a random process with memory

Tags: stochastic-processes, random-variables, random, correlation, stochastic-analysis

I'm modeling a digital system as a random process and attempting to solve for the autocorrelation in order to arrive at the power spectral density of the process. The system is as follows:

- At any step k, one of four networks n0 - n3 is active
- When network n2 is active, the output is x2 (some integer value)
- Initially, the probability that any network is active is equal (1/4)
- The rule is that a network can not be active the next two cycles after it is selected
- Besides this rule, all networks are equally likely to be selected
- Hence n0 - n1 - n2 - n0 is a valid sequence but n0 - n1 - n0 - n2 is not

Now I'm using MATLAB so I have been able to model this process (call it X[k]), verify it's correct, and plot the autocorrelation (lets call it R[n]) and PSD.

(IMAGE WOULD GO HERE IF I COULD POST IT)

This is using: x0=200, x1=-100, x2=400, x3=-500 (zero mean)

That is all well and good, but it's not very satisfying. I'd like to be able to arrive at R[n] theoretically as well.

Using the definition, $R[n] = E[X[k]X[k+n]] = \sum_{i=0}^{3}\sum_{j=0}^{3}X_iX_jp_{X_iX_j}$

R[0] is simply the second moment of the RV X or 115000 with the numbers above, which matches MATLAB. Simple enough.

R[1] requires $p_{X_0X_1}$ to compute. Intuitively it is clear that the probability of X[1] = X[0] is 0 and otherwise the probabilities are equal, so 1/12 for the rest. This gives us R[1] = -38333 using the above numbers, which also matches MATLAB. The same idea gives us R[2] = R[1] = -38333.

Now when we get to R[3] computing $p_{X_0X_3}$ becomes trickier. My initial thought was that they would be independent at this point since the rule only has a "depth" of 2 samples. But after thinking about it, if X[0] = x0 and we want to know probability of X[3], then it has a 50% chance of being x0 and a 50% chance of being "other" - x1/x2/x3. Then for $p_{X_0X_3}$ the value of $X[0] = x_i, X[3] = x_i$ would be 0.5*1/4 = 1/8 (on the diagonal), and the other values would be 1/24 since they are equally likely. This gives a value for R[3] of +38333 which also agrees with MATLAB. Huzzah!

For R[4] and $p_{X_0X_4}$ I again looked at the "diagonal" $X[0] = x_i, X[4] = x_i$ and said OK, since in the previous step there was a 50% chance that $X[0] = x_i, X[3] = x_i$, there was a 50% chance that it was not equal, and then a 50% chance from there that the new value at X[4] would be equal. This gives me $p_{X_0X_4}$ where all the values are equal, 1/16, hence R[4] = 0.

Now at this point I'm a little stuck on how to compute the remaining values. However I think one idea that works is to draw a Trellis diagram of the four states vs the index k and the transitions available and their probability. I think that the joint pmf's can be calculated by looking at all the paths that connect X[0] = x0 to X[5] = x0, for example. For each path, multiply out the probabilities for the path to give the probability of the sequence ie x0-x1-x2-x3-x1-x0 would be 1/4*1/3*1/2*1/2*1/2*1/2. Then sum all of the path probabilities that start with x0 and end with x0. Then do this for all values of X[0] and X[5].

I believe this works however it does not seem very efficient. I've been trying to come up with an easier way to compute the joint pmfs for some values of k but I haven't been able to get anywhere. Any ideas or help would be much appreciated.

Comment: "When network n2 is active, the output is x2" Not clear for me. x2 is a constant ? What do you know about the output $x_i[n]$ of each network?

Comment: Yes x2 is a constant. X[k] can take on x0, x1, x2, x3. You can basically ignore n0, I was just trying to say that there are four networks but when each one is active it has an integer output x0 (or x1 or x2 etc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $a_1 = 200$, $a_2=-100$, $a_3=400$, $a_4=-500$. We have a (second order) Markov process 
$X_t=a_i$ with $i$ taking values equiprobably in two possible values that verify $X_t \ne X_{t-1}$ and $X_t \ne X_{t-2}$

The problem is quite simplified by the fact that $\sum a_i=0$ and the (intuively obvious and provable via Markov chain theory) that in equlibrium the states are equiprobable.

Now, I claim:  Then $r_k=E(X_t \, X_{t-k}) = \frac{4 c_k -1}{3} \, \sigma_x^2$,
where $c_k = P(X_t = X_{t-k})$ and $\sigma_x^2 = \sum \frac{1}{4} a_i^2 = 115000$

Proof: $$r_k=E(X_t \, X_{t-k}) = E(X_0 \, X_k)=\sum_i \sum_j a_i a_j P(X_0 = a_i ; X_k = a_j)=\\=\sum_i a_i P(X_0 = a_i) \sum_j a_j P(X_k=a_j|X_0=a_i) \tag{1}$$

We separate in the inner sum the term with same index as the outer sum

$$\sum_j a_j P(X_k=a_j|X_0=a_i)= a_i P(X_k=a_i|X_0=a_i) + \sum_{j\ne i} a_j P(X_k=a_j|X_0=a_i)=\\=a_i c_k +  (-a_i) \frac{1- c_k}{n-1} =a_i \frac{( n \, c_k -1)}{n-1} \tag{2}$$

where $n=4$ in our case. Above we've used the facts: $P(X_k=a_i|X_0=a_i)=c_k$ (probability that the same networks is selected, $k$ steps apart) does not depend on $i$;  $P(X_k=a_j|X_0=a_i)$ (once fixed $i$ and $k$), is constant over all the $n-1$ values ${j\ne i}$, hence its value is $(1-c_k)/(n-1)$

Then

$$r_k=\sum_i a_i P(X_0 = a_i)  a_i \frac{ n\, c_k -1}{n-1} = \frac{ n\, c_k -1}{n-1} \frac{\sum a_i^2}{n} = \frac{ 4 c_k -1}{3} \sigma_X^2 \tag{3}$$

Now we are left with calculation of $c_k$. By the symmetry of the problem,
this is equivalent of computing the probability that $p(X_k=a_1| X_0=a_1)$ 
It's obvious that $c_k=1$ $c_k=1$ for $k=0$, $c_k=0$ for $k=1,2$ 
For larger values of $k$, the probability can be computed considering a Markov chain with three states, with the following transition matrix:

$$ M=\pmatrix{ 0 &  1 & 0 \\ 0&    0 & 1 \\1/2&   0&   1/2}$$

The state vector, for each time step $k$, correspond to the three possibilites: $\{X_k=a_1; X_k=a_1;X_k\ne a_1 \cap X_{k-1} =a_1; \textrm{elsewhere}\}$

That is:

- state $0\equiv$ $a_1$ has just happened, it won't happen again in next two steps.
- state $1\equiv$ $a_1$ has happened in the previous, it won't happen again in next step.
- state $2\equiv$ $a_1$ has not happened in this or the previous, it can happen with probability $1/2$ in the next, or elsewhere we'll return to this state.

The desired probability $c_k$ is the probability that, starting from state 0, we are revisiting it at step $k$. Then,

$$c_k = M^{[k]}_{0,0} \hspace{1cm} M^{[k]}=\pmatrix{ 0 &  1 & 0 \\ 0&    0 & 1 \\1/2&   0&   1/2}^k$$

```
k   ck        r
0   1       115000
1   0       -38333
2   0       -38333
3   0.5      38333
4   0.25         0 
5   0.125   -19166
6   0.3125    9583
7   0.28125   4791
8   0.20313  -7186
9   0.25781   1197
10  0.26953   2994
```

Comment: Thanks. I think the key here is that it is a 2nd order Markov model - the textbook I have didn't cover this possibility.

However I'm a little confused by some points in your answer. You claim that $c_k$=1 for k=1,2 - do you mean $c_k$=0? 

Also, while your response is helpful and seemingly accurate, it is essentially just providing me with the solution and doesn't really describe how you arrived there. Could you describe $M^{[k]}$ and $c_k$ please? How did these lead you to that expression for $r_k$?

Comment: @Ottfather Fixed the error with $c_k$. Sorry for the sketchy answer, I'll give you more details soon (I had addded lot of details just recently but Chrome crashed and I lost everything ...)

Comment: OK so I see that $c_k$ is sort of extrapolating on what I was noticing for $P(X[k] = X[0])$. Basically, after setting $X[0]=x0$, then $P(X[k] = X[0])=c_k=0.5c_{k-1}+0.5c_{k-3}$. In other words, the probability that at time k the output is x0 is equal to 50% of the probability that it was x0 three cycles ago (imagine starting at k=3 and looking back at k=0) as well as 50% of the probability that x0 was NOT selected (equivalent to WAS selected) during the previous cycle (imagine k=4). I don't quite understand the need for the matrix M above. Then again, I'm a n00b here.

Comment: Excellent, thank you. I actually arrived at the same thing once I found the algorithm for $c_k$. I went about it a little differently, I split the initial definition for $r_k$ into the sum of equal terms (i=j) and non-equal, but otherwise the same approach. However I still don't quite understand why matrix M is 3x3 and not 4x4, if it is a transition matrix. In fact I thought with a second-order Markov the transition matrix would be 16x16 or 16x4. Can you explain that part? Thanks again, really appreciate the help!